# How can I save and export my tensorflow model to use in a different piece of code?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm making a chess engine using TensorFlow and keras, and after training my model I want to save all of its weights and biases etcetera and then be able to use it in a completely independent piece of code - say, an app. So basically I want to export the final feedforward settings to use to predict any input given.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please reformulate your question.

There is a detailed guide regarding saving keras models at
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize

Do you have additional questions not solved by that doc ?

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect! All I really needed was direction to a resource like that, I couldn't find any on my own (probably searching the wrong keywords). How do you recommend I reformulate my question, or is it a hopeless case?